# General solution for a linear system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Find the general solution to the linear system $\frac{du}{dt}=Au$ for
> the following matrices:
>
> a.) $\pmatrix{2&1\\0&2}$
>
> b.) $\pmatrix{-1&-1\\4&-5}$

- I got the eigenvalues for a:

  $\lambda = 2,2$ repeated roots and the eigenvector, $v_1=\pmatrix{0\\1}$, so the general solution is $c_1e^{2t} + c_2te^{2t}$ but the answer is $\pmatrix{c_1e^{2t}+c_2te^{2t}\\c_2e^{2t}}$. How did they get that?
- For b,
  $\lambda = -3,-3$ and eigenvector, $v_1=\pmatrix{1\\2}$ but the answer is $\pmatrix{c_1e^{-3t}+c_2(\frac{1}{2} +t)e^{-3t}\\2c_1e^{-3t}+2c_2te^{-3t}}$ how did they get that?

Comment: What method are you using to compute the solutions? Are you trying to find $e^{At}$?

Comment: @JacobSchlather yes, i am. I am taking the eigenvalues of each matrix and finding $e^{At}$ like you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For linear systems $\dot{u} = Au$, the general solution is $u = e^{At}u_0$.

The way to calculate this is by $e^{At}u_0 = e^{(A-\lambda I)t}e^{\lambda t}u_0 = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (A- \lambda I)^k \frac{t^k}{k!} e^{\lambda t}u_0 = \sum_{k=0}^{mult(\lambda) - 1} (A- \lambda I)^k \frac{t^k}{k!} e^{\lambda t}u_0$. Which is true if $u_0$ is in the eigenspace of $\lambda$.

So in general, $e^{At}u_0 = \sum_i \sum_{k=0}^{mult(\lambda_i) - 1} (A- \lambda_i I)^k \frac{t^k}{k!} e^{\lambda_i t}u_0^{(i)}$, where ${u_0}^{(i)}$ is the component of $u_0$ in the eigenspace of $\lambda_i$. And $mult(\lambda_i)$ is the geometric multiplicity of $\lambda_i$.

For (a), your eigenvalue is 2 with geometric multiplicty of 2.

The first term in the series will be $e^{2t}u_0 = e^{2t} \pmatrix{c_1 \\ c_2}$
And the second term in the series is $(A- 2 I) t e^{2 t}u_0 = te^{2t} \pmatrix{0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0} \pmatrix{c_1 \\ c_2} = te^{2t} \pmatrix{c_2 \\ 0}$

Adding the two yields solution $\pmatrix{e^{2t}c_1 + te^{2t}c_2 \\ e^{2t}c_2}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that!!! And can you write out the computation please, so that I can understand the equation you just provided?

Comment: Added computation for part (a)

Comment: Stuart, how come you did $(A- 2 I) t e^{2 t}u_0 = te^{2t} \pmatrix{0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0} \pmatrix{c_1 \\ c_2} = te^{2t} \pmatrix{c_2 \\ 0}$ for the second one but not for the first one $e^{2t}u_0 = e^{2t} \pmatrix{c_1 \\ c_2}$?

Comment: Because that's what the series says to do xD

Comment: I am going to need to do a lot more practice then :)

Answer (score 1):

For the first system you do not need any eigenvalues or eigenvectors. Note that the second equation has the form
$$
\dot u_2=2u_2.
$$
Hence the solution
$$
u_2(t)=c_2e^{2t}.
$$
You plug it into the first equation and get
$$
\dot u_1=2u_1+c_2e^{2t}.
$$
This is a first order linear equation and can be solved by any appropriate method, e.g., by the method of integrating factor:
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(u_1e^{-2t})=c_2\Rightarrow u_1=c_2te^{2t}+c_1e^{2t}.
$$
So the general solution is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
u_1\\
u_2
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}c_1e^{2t}+c_2te^{2t}\\
c_2e^{2t}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
For the second problem you will need a generalized vector that satisfies $(A-\lambda I)^2v=0$. Any vector will satisfy this equation (why), and hence we can take the one which is simply looking and linearly independent of what you already have found. E.g., $v^{T}=(1,0)$ works.

Hence the general solution would be
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
u_1\\
u_2
\end{bmatrix}=c_1\begin{bmatrix}1\\
2
\end{bmatrix} e^{-3t}+c_2(I+(A-\lambda I)t)ve^{-3t}
$$
and you get your (almost, up to a mulplicative constant) answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Stuart answered it, but this is very useful too!